# How to get internal variables for a custom loss function in tensorflow keras api?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to add an L1 loss of the batch normalization scaling factors for [network slimming](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06519.pdf).

for example let's take a simple mnist classifier:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
conv_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
bn_1 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_1)
conv_2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(bn_1)
bn_2 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_2)
conv_3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(bn_2)
bn_3 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_3)
conv_4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
    32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(bn_3)
bn_4 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_4)
conv_5 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
    10, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same')(bn_4)
bn_5 = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_5)
gap = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(bn_5)
outputs = keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(gap)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

My goal is to find the relative importance of each convolution filter channel via the scaling factors of the bn_* layers so that I can remove them.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: keep  a reference of each BatchNormalization layer like `bn_1_layer=keras.layers.BatchNormalization()` and you can get all variables belonging to it with `bn_1_layer.variables`